# How to stack many images sequentially to build a bigger tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am processing a tensor that has the following shape: `[frame, channel, height, width]`. I would like to extract each frame from the tensor, which can be easily done by `[frame_number, :,:,:]`. I then continue to process that particular frame of dimension `[channel, height, width]`

But I a finding it difficult to stack them back into another tensor of shape `[frame, channel, height, width]` sequentially as I process each frame. (That is, this tensor will grow in axis 0)

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You simple use tf.stack ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack)) to combine them. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.Variable(np.ones([2, 3, 4, 5]))

# Slice a
b = a[0, :, :, :]
c = a[1, :, :, :]

# Stack b, c. Result should be the same as a
d = tf.stack([b, c])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  assert sess.run(a).all() == sess.run(d).all()
```